# QXmlStreamWriter writes different start of the root element when not writing any text elements

Tags: qt, xmlwriter, qtxml

This is code without writing any text elements to the xml file:

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Vytvorenie databázy", QDir::currentPath(), "XML file(*.xml)");
QFile file(filename);
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
xmlWriter.setAutoFormattingIndent(4);
xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
xmlWriter.writeStartElement("CARS");
//
//
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();
file.close();
```

This is output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CARS/>
```

This is wanted output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CARS>
</CARS>
```

Why does it not write start of root element when not writing any additional elements? Is there a way how to explicitly tell writer to write it even when no more elements are added? Same thing happens in C#.

Comment: Why do you need that? Both are semantically equivalent and should be interpreted the same by every parser. I don't think you can influence this.

Comment: I had some problems reading empty xml files correctly. Then i found out that i was doing it wrong and it does not matter as u said, they are semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an inside implementation of QXmlStreamWriter and it does not matter, because both are semantically equivalent and "should be interpreted the same by every parser", as commenter wrote.